# Why am I getting "Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: String String.valueOf(Object)"?

Tags: apex, parameters, static

I have this static class called from my lightning component, but am getting the error

> "Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: String String.valueOf(Object)"

on the line where I try and calculate a start date from the string passed. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void generatePDF(myRec__c rec, string selquarter){
    string selqenddate = selquarter.substringBetween('(', ')');
    date startdate = (selqenddate.valueOf(selqenddate)).addMonths(-3).startofMonth;
    myPDF(rec.id, '', '');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The string class's `valueOf()` method is a static method.

Static methods need to be called like this: `Class.staticMethodName()` i.e. `String.valueOf()`

What you're currently doing is using an *instance* of a string to try to call a static method, which (as the error indicates) is not allowed.

bad:

```
selqenddate.valueOf(selqenddate)
```

good:

```
String.valueOf(selqenddate)
```

Of course, you don't need to use `String.valueOf()` at all here because `selquarter` is a string, and `substringBetween()` also returns a string.

Instead, you need to be using a method that takes a `String` as input, and gives you a `Date` as output such as `Date.parse()`

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you are trying to use a static method `valueOf`from `String` class on an instance of a `String` named `selqenddate`, which is not allowed.

You are most likely are trying to construct a date from a string value, and that you will need to utilize the [`Date.valueOf()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)instead. Your code should look like something as below:

```
Date startdate = 
    (Date.valueOf(selqenddate))
        .addMonths(-3)
            .toStartOfMonth();
```

Note, there’s no property `startOfMonth` on `Date` class.